# Azure AD application, cordova, adal-angular, windows phone 8 redirect url

Tags: angularjs, cordova, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to build an cordova application that can authenticate against Azure Active Directory through [adal-angular](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js), this works fine on android and iOS, but on Windows Phone 8 the redirect url scheme is different and I get en error that redirect url 'x-wmapp0:www/index.html' is not allowed. When I try to add this url to the AzureAD app config it isn't valid. (which it of course isn't it doesnt have :// in it)

Does anybody here have had any experience with authentication through this route?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For Cordova apps we recommend the use of our ADAL cordova plugin, which makes better use of local resources. Please see http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/04/06/adal-plugin-for-apache-cordova-deep-dive/